# macOS Big Sur - Can't install Brew

Tags: git, macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I hit the following command in terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

But it showing me the following error:
[image]

Comment: The command is provided on the official site: 
https://brew.sh/

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10368 -- "Everything you've posted suggests that you're actually overwriting an _existing_ install that has a b0rken core tap."

Comment: Thanks, @Joe. I've done the mentioned steps in the provided thread. Now it's installing. I hope it will resolve the issue.